# What is the *standard duality argument?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the *standard duality argument?* I saw this foor exemplo in the following statement. The case $p < 2$ follows from the standard duality argument. To prove

> **Theorem:** [Calderón Zigmund] If $u$ is a solution of
>   \begin{equation}
> \Delta u = f \quad \mbox{in} \quad B_2
> \end{equation}
>   then
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{B_2} | D^2u|^p \le \Bigl(\int_{B_2} |f|^p + \int_{B_2} |u|^p \Bigr) \quad \mbox{for any} 1<p<  + \infty.
> \end{equation}

Comment: What is $B_2$, exactly?

Comment: The ball centered at origin and radius 2.

Comment: Perhaps they mean the duality in $L^p$ spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_p = -\Delta$, $A_p : W^{1,p} \to (W^{1,p'})'$ for $1 < p < \infty$, where $p'$ is the adjoint exponent with $1 = 1/p + 1/p'$.

First, you prove that $A_p$ is invertible for $p \in [2,\infty)$. The duality argument simply means that the adjoint of $A_p$ is $A_{p'}$. Then, the (bounded) invertibility for $A_{p'}$ follows from the (bounded) invertibility of $A_p$.

Answer (score 1):

Alberto Calderón and Antoni Zygmund have nothing to do with this theorem that cannot be true without specifying some boundary condition at $\partial B_2$. The missing boundary condition is of course a terrible blunder making it easy, for example, to establish that the subspace of all harmonic functions in $W^{2,p}(B_2)$ is finite-dimensional, which is obviously absurd. There are only two options to correct the blunder and relate the estimate to the Calderón–Zygmund theorem: replace the ball $B_2$ by the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$, or otherwise replace $B_2$ in the left-hand side by a smaller ball, say $B_1\subset B_2\,$, inserting in either case a constant factor $C_p\,$ into the right-hand side of the esimate. Without such factor, depending on $p$, the estimate cannot be made valid for any $p\in (1,\infty)$, since due to 
$C_p=1$  solutions would necessarily stay bounded while $p\to 1\,$ or $\,p\to \infty\,$, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: To disprove the pseudo "Calderon-Zygmund theorem" in the OP, it suffices to notice that the estimate cannot hold for all solutions $u\in W^{2,p}(B_2)$ corresponding to some given $f$, say, $f=0$. Indeed, the estimate implies that a closed ball in the subspace $H^{2,p}(B_2)$ of all harmonic functions in $W^{2,p}(B_2)$ is compact since the embedding of $W^{2,p}(B_2)$ into $L^p(B_2)$ is known to be compact. Hence the subspace $H^{2,p}(B_2)$ is to be locally compact, which equals its being finite-dimensional, i.e., equals nonsense.